Losing precision after converting float to string in c++
I have converted string value to float and tried to set precision to it. After setting precision I am getting truncated value.
    #include<iostream>
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    int main()
    {
        std::string str ="1570734298.45";
        float val= stof(str);
        std::cout<<val<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(6)<<val;
        return 0;
    }

Output:
1.57073e+09
1570734336.000000


Side note: Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?

1570734298.45 can't be represented in float with the zero precision. You should forget about float in the 21th century.

Do you expect to have an infinite number of bits to store your floats in? You should watch this Floating Point Numbers - Computerphile, its fun and will help you understand things a lot better

No. You lost it when converting the string to float. A float only has 6.9 decimal digits of precision for integers. Not ten as you are expecting.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

This does not depend on the string conversion. It's the limit of the float datatype. If you use double everything works fine:
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    std::string str ="1570734298.45";
    float val= stof(str);
    std::cout<<val<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(6)<<val << std::endl;
    val = 1570734298.45f;
    std::cout<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(6)<<val<< std::endl;
    
    double valD = stod(str);
    std::cout<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(6)<<valD << std::endl;
    valD = 1570734298.45;
    std::cout<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(6)<<valD << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Output
1.57073e+09
1570734336.000000
1570734336.000000
1570734298.450000
1570734298.450000


Only for that particular example. Using double just moves the point of failure out to 16 decimal digits but the intrinsic problem remains - there is no finite binary representation of 0.1 so that rounding errors are inevitable when a decimal string is converted into floating point machine representation. It is usually enough though.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.
